# Ruby: iterate over two array of hashes and create array of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-2.4

I have two arrays of hashes

1. `rtg` with keys `id, position_id, valid_from, valid_to`
2. `inv` with keys `id, position_id, date`

Examples look like this:

```
rtg=[{:id=>7, :position_id=>3, :valid_from=>Tue, 05 Sep 2017 10:00:00 EEST +03:00, :valid_to=>Tue, 05 Sep 2017 10:59:59 EEST +03:00},
 {:id=>6, :position_id=>3, :valid_from=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 22:00:00 EEST +03:00, :valid_to=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 23:59:59 EEST +03:00},
 {:id=>1, :position_id=>2, :valid_from=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 07:00:00 EEST +03:00, :valid_to=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 08:00:00 EEST +03:00}]

inv=[{:id=>23, :position_id=>3, :date=>Tue, 05 Sep 2017 10:10:00 EEST +03:00},
 {:id=>17, :position_id=>3, :date=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 22:45:00 EEST +03:00},
 {:id=>11, :position_id=>3, :date=>Mon, 04 Sep 2017 07:20:00 EEST +03:00}]
```

I need to create array of arrays with `id` pairs from `rtg` and `inv` hashes where

1) `position_id` match and

2) `date` from `inv` is in rage of `valid_from` & `valid_to` from `rtg`

**How do I do this, please?**

In my example above result would be:
`result = [[7,23],[6,17]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use nested `each` to compare each item in both arrays, grabbing the `id`s for those items that match the conditions; for example:

```
rtg.each_with_object([]) do |r, result|
  inv.each do |i|
    if i[:position_id] == r[:position_id] && i[:date].between?(r[:valid_from], r[:valid_to])
      result << [r[:id], i[:id]]
    end
  end
end

#=> [[7, 23], [6, 17]]
```

Comment: Thank you. I tweaked @Nimish Gupta answer to `find` method instead of `find_by` + I had to do `inventory[:position_id]` etc. like you do it.  Do you think there could be any performance increase with your code in case I have thousands of items to iterate over?

Comment: @matiss Since you need to compare each item of `rtg` to each of `inv` (i.e. _O(n^2)_), performance will **decrease** (i.e. it will take more time to execute) as your arrays grow bigger.

Comment: Sure, iteration performace will descrease if arrays grow. I was thinking more  about `each_with_object` method. Anyway, your code works nice, thank you!

Comment: @matiss  No, using `each_with_object` will not affect performance at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
array = []
rtg.each do |record|
  matched_record = inv.find { |inventory| inventory[:position_id] == record[:position_id] && inventory[:date].to_i.in?(record[:valid_from].to_i..record[:valid_to].to_i) }
  array << [record.id, matched_record.id] if matched_record
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, however I get this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method "find_by" for [7, 6, 1]:Array Did you mean?  min_by`

Comment: I had name mismatch in my method, however I still get an error like this: `NoMethodError: undefined method "find_by" for #<Array:0x007fffe909a498>`

Comment: I had a silly mistake while typing
It should be `find` instead of `find_by`

Comment: Yes, it has to be `find` + you would need to change for example `inventory.position_id` to `inventory[:position_id]` If you correct your answer, I'll be happy top up-vote as it generally works.